# MATLAB - Loop through a size-variant array?

Tags: matlab

I have an array `a` and a `new_elem`.

- If `new_elem` is smaller than any existing member in `a`, then it is not allowed to be added into `a`.
- On the contrary, if `new_elem` is larger than any existing member in `a`, then it is allowed to be added into `a`, **and** those existing elements smaller than `new_elem` have to be kicked out.

I implemented this as follows.

```
a = [a new_elem]; % add in first
for idx = 1:1:numel(a)-1
    % new_elem < some existing member
    if a(idx) > new_elem
        a = a(1:end-1); % kick new_elem out
        break;
    % new_elem > some existing member    
    elseif a(idx) < new_elem
        a(a==a(idx)) = []; % kick that exisiting member out
    end
end
```

The snippet works when `new_elem` is smaller, e.g.,

```
new_elem = 4;
a = [5 5 5 5 5];
```

It fails with the error **`Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`**
 in the other cases, e.g.,

```
new_elem = 6;
a = [5 5 5 5 5];
```

I understand that the problem is once we kick out an existing element, the size of `a` changes, and hence, we will have trouble indexing the final element, since `numel(a)` has been evaluated before the loop starts.

How could I fix it?

P.S.: This is a simplified version of my problem and actually involves a lot more. So please kindly do not subversively modify the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just get a list/array of all elements in `a` that are less than `new_elem` and make your decision based on that, avoiding loops altogether?

```
% get a list of all indices of elements in a that are less than new_elem
minIdcs = find(a<new_elem);

% if the length of this list is less than the length of a, then there is at
% least one element in a that is greater than new_elem - so only add new_elem
% if the lengths are identical
if length(minIdcs) == length(a)
    % remove all elements of a that are less than new_elem
    a(minIdcs) = [];

    % now add new_elem to a
    a = [a new_elem];
end
```

This works but I am not sure if it compatible with what you intended as your code is dependent upon the order of the elements in `a`:  `new_elem` may be smaller than at least one element in `a`, but that element may not be encountered for several iterations of  the loop, so other elements  of `a` might be removed before we make the decision that `new_elem` should not be added.

If order is important, then you could use a `while` loop instead

```
a = [a new_elem]; % add in first
idx = 1;
n   = length(a);
while idx < n
    % new_elem < some existing member
    if a(idx) > new_elem
        a = a(1:end-1); % kick new_elem out
        break;
    % new_elem > some existing member    
    elseif a(idx) < new_elem
        a(idx) = []; % kick that exisiting member out
        n = n-1;
    else
        idx=idx+1;
    end
end
```

The above is very similar to what you have - we just need to keep track of the number of elements in the list (which is adjusted whenever we remove an element) and we need to increment the index `idx` only when we don't remove an element.  And rather than removing all elements that are less than `new_elem` in one-shot, we handle them on a case-by-case basis (so `a(idx) = [];` rather than `a(a==a(idx)) = [];`).

Comment: The slight modifications upon my extant algorithm works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just this simple code should do what you want:

```
if new_elem > min(a)
a = [new_elem a(find(new_elem < a))]
end
```